# Blinking taskbar icon in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows, browser, taskbar

I have built an instant chat tool that works perfectly most of the part, I'm having a few issues with alerting users when a new chat  arrives, I have this working fine on XP and also on 7 providing the taskbar icons are not combined, is there a way to either focus the window or blink the taskbar icon when the user has the taskbar icons combined in windows 7?

My current method is to change the page title on the arrival of a new message using the titlealert jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can focus the window with

```
window.focus()
```

But that does not always work. 
The possibility to let the taskbar icon blink is not available.

Comment: Focus appears to work fine when using IE, i'm surprised there's no way to make it blink though?

Comment: You could make a switch every 1s between blur and focus (blur = unfocus)